# How to hide entity from specific players?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-addons

I have not found anything on this issue, I myself have no idea even how to implement it, maybe someone knows how to do this somehow? (v1.20.51)

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! On Minecraft commands questions, please see our [guide on what to do before asking a Minecraft commands question](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13507/4797), especially the part about “what you’ve tried so far”, and edit in the requested information to your post.